# Creating half circle chart filled with gradient

Tags: html, css, pie-chart, linear-gradients

I managed to create simple chart with a border. I'd like to change simple **border-color** to a gradient. I was trying to use **border-image** or **background** property, but it's seems impossible to curve it so it can fit arched shape of a container. **Is there any way to achieve that effect in css3 ?**

**HTML**

```
<div class="pie">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pie {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 116px;
    height: 58px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pie *,
.pie::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pie::before {
    content: '';
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border: 20px solid grey;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 175px;
    border-top-right-radius: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
}

.pie .overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border: 20px solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 175px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 175px;
    transform-origin: 50% 0;
    border-color:yellow;/* background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(228,232,7,1) 0%, rgba(0,218,156,1) 100%); */
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Creating a Gradient Torus in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137477/3162554) and [Codepen: 'svg donut + liner gradient '](https://codepen.io/sixsided/pen/ZYdZvG).

Comment: Do you need the inner circle to be transparent ?

Comment: No, just a gradient on top of a solid color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `pie`'s pseudo and the `overlay` as the white center, you can do like this

```css
.pie {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 200px 200px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pie::after {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);      /*  set rotation degree  */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(228,232,7,1) 0%, rgba(0,218,156,1) 100%);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.pie::before {
    border: 20px solid grey;
}
.pie .overlay{
    top: 20px;                      /*  match border width  */
    left: 20px;                     /*  match border width  */
    width: calc(100% - 40px);       /*  match border width times 2  */
    height: calc(200% - 40px);      /*  match border width times 2  */
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;                     /*  move it on top of the pseudo elements  */
}
.pie *,
.pie::before,
.pie::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
    <span class="overlay"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with 2 gradients, the inner masking the outer:

```css
.test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(to left, red, green);
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box, border-box; 
    border: solid 50px transparent;
    border-radius: 200px 200px 0px 0px;
    border-width: 50px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

```css
.test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-origin: content-box; 
    border: solid 50px transparent;
    border-radius: 200px 200px 0px 0px;
    padding: 50px 50px 0px 50px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -25%;
    top: -50%;
    right: 0px;
    height: 300%;
    width: 150%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red, green);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: spin 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional pseudo element on `.pie` (an `::after`), position them as overlapping it at its top-left and top-right corners, curve them both, and use `background` for the gradient.

Then, position the `span` at the center of `.pie` and give it a white background (as opposed to transparent) with a higher `z-index` to make sure the center of the arc remains in tact.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, azure, slategray);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, midnightblue, steelblue);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
div span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  background: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but it's just a single curved gradient filling whole semi-circle. Point of using "transform: rotate(90deg);" is to give different values to different charts to overlay main container.

Comment: It is actually two parts with different gradients. I just made the two gradients opposite of each other to make them look like one big one. I have updated the colors to show the two parts now. If that's not what you want, then it might be good to include a picture of your desired result in your post.

Comment: It has to be more dynamic. I need to have this overlay gradient filling with different sizes, like 80%, 25%, 30%(of a half pie), which i calculate by 180deg=100%.

Comment: You could accomplish something like that with a more complex gradient, such as `linear-gradient(125deg, red, red 30%, blue 30%, blue 60%, gold 60% gold)`, but the shape of the pieces will not be a nice wedge shape like you probably want. More complex markup would be necessary.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a pie chart that you could just cover the bottom half of and then position a circle-shaped div on top of to make your desired arc shape. [See here about pie charts](https://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish). Also, it'd be good to update your question with all these requirements.

Comment: I mean, my requirements are not that complicated, basically I just want to substitute yellow color in code I posted with a gradient, but just for an example i used 90deg which is 50% of a semi-circle, but it might be different number like i said - 35%, 80%. Maybe your approach with gradient percentage would be ok with putting grey at the end, but I didn't test it yet.

Comment: Will there always be only just two colors in the arc, or could it be several colors?

Comment: Solid grey for an arc , and simple gradient that blends 2 colors, on top of it.